# Optional params with Play 2 and Swagger

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, swagger, swagger-play2

I'm trying to use Swagger to document a Play 2 REST API but `swagger-play2` doesn't seem to understand optional parameters defined with Scala's `Option` type - the normal way to make a param optional in Play 2:

```
GET /documents controllers.DocumentController.getDocuments(q: Option[String])
```

I want the `q` param to be optional. There is a matching annotated controller method with this `Option[String]` param. On startup I'm getting `UNKOWN TYPE` in the log and the json produced by api-docs breaks `swagger-ui`:

```
UNKNOWN TYPE: scala.Option
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Is there another way to specify an optional parameter in Play 2 and have Swagger understand it?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I've found so far is to remove the param from the params list, use Swagger's `@ApiImplicitParams` annotation and grab the param from the request object in your controller method. Swagger will then consider the param to be optional.

```
GET /documents controllers.DocumentController.getDocuments()
```

and then in the controller:

```
@ApiOperation(...)
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "q", value = "Query", required = false, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
))
def getDocuments = Action { implicit request => 
  // use param via request object
}
```

This is certainly not as nice as using Scala's Option type but it produces correct Swagger docs.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this similarly to @Tom Wadley's answer.

This code creates the problem:

```
@ApiOperation( ... )
def foo(@ApiParam(value="Argument 1") @PathParam("a1") a1 : Option[Int]) = ...
```

To avoid the problem just remove the annotations from the argument, and instead declare an implicit parameter with the same name:

```
@ApiOperation( ... )
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(new ApiImplicitParam(name="a1", dataType="Int", required=false, paramType="query", ...)
def foo(a1 : Option[Int]) = ...
```

(Scala 2.11.2, Play 2.3, Swagger 1.3.8)

I logged [Issue 706](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/706) against Swagger too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this lib 
https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger

This library takes a different approach than annotation (which force you into learning a new API), you write swagger spec directly in your routes file as comments. It automatically generates parameters definition based on routes file and **for Option[T] typed parameters it automatically mark them as required=false.**

Answer (score 0):

The APIImplicitParam workaround was not working for me.

Another workaround is to omit the option param from the routes

```
GET /documents controllers.DocumentController.getDocuments()
```

But grab it in the code:

```
val qSeq = request.queryString.get("q")
val q = qSeq match {
  case None => None
  case Some(seq) => seq.headOption
}
```

and annotate it with ApiImplicitParam for Swagger docs